# How to check if records within selected date using multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, multiple-columns, multiple-tables

It is an additional question to my previous one that is already answered.

There are 4 tables: buildings, rooms, reservations, information

1 building = n rooms
1 room = n reservations

TABLE BUILDINGS - ID(int), name(varchar)
TABLE ROOMS - ID(int), building_id(int)
TABLE RESERVATIONS - ID(int), room_id(int), date_start(datetime), date_end(datetime)
TABLE INFORMATION - ID(int), building_id(int), hours_start(int), hours_end(int)

### Buildings table example

```
ID    name
1     Building A
2     Building B
3     Building C
```

### Rooms table example

```
ID    building_id
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     3
```

### Reservations table example

```
ID    room_id     date_start            date_end  
1     1           2014-08-09 14:00:00   2014-08-09 14:30:00
2     1           2014-08-09 14:30:00   2014-08-09 15:30:00
3     3           2014-08-09 16:30:00   2014-08-09 17:30:00
4     2           2014-08-09 16:00:00   2014-08-09 17:00:00
5     3           2014-08-09 16:00:00   2014-08-09 16:30:00
```

### Information table example

```
ID    building_id   hours_start   hours_end
1     1             9             22
2     2             8             20
3     3             8             22
```

### Question

Can we filter buildings that has atleast 1 available room on selected date in any hour? Buildings working hours may be different (Information table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want.  It calculates the total number of meeting hours in the building for all the rooms.  It then calculates the total meeting hours.  If a room is available the second is less than the first:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name,
       sum(timestampdiff(minute, rv.date_start, rv.date_end))/60 as MeetingHours,
       max(hours_end - hours_start)*count(distinct r.id) as BuildingHours
FROM buildings b JOIN
     information bi
     on b.id = bi.building_id
     rooms r
     ON b.id = r.building_id LEFT JOIN
     reservations rv
     ON rv.room_id = r.id AND
        '2014-08-09' between date(rv.date_start) AND date(rv.date_end)
GROUP BY b.id
HAVING MeetingHours is Null or MeetingHours < BuildingHours;
```

Comment: SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(... returns NULL. Why could that be?

Comment: @user3924829 . . . That would occur when there are no reservations on that day in the building.  Clearly a room is then available, which is why the `having` clause has `MeetingHours is null`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But strangely it always returns NULL even if whole building is booked. And it's not working right at the moment because of this value.

Comment: @user3924829 . . . The problem is the `on` clause comparison.  A date at midnight is never going to be "between" two dates with hours.  I just fixed that.

Comment: Exactly that! Now it works perfectly. Thanks again Gordon, this solution is amazing.